# Don't Understand what's wrong with my Code, FreeCodeCamp (NodeJS)

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am studying `nodejs` from **freecodecamp and nodeschool**. I was stuck several hours to find the mistake of my code and still I can't understand the difference.

It would be awesome if someone explain ***what is wrong with my code***.

*Learnyounode problem name* **FILETRED LS**.

***My Code***

```
var fs = require('fs'), path = require('path');

var directoryName = process.argv[2];
var extentionName = '.'+process.argv[3];

fs.readdir(directoryName, function(err, data) {
    if (err) {
        throw err;
    }

    var newExt = path.extname(data);

    for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
        if (newExt.toString() === extentionName.toString()) {
            console.log(data[i]);
        }
    }
});
```

***Solution Code***

```
var fs = require('fs')
var path = require('path')

var folder = process.argv[2]
var ext = '.' + process.argv[3]

fs.readdir(folder, function (err, files) {
    if (err) return console.error(err)

    files.forEach(function(file) {
        if (path.extname(file) === ext) {
            console.log(file)
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: look at where they use `path.extname(file)` and compare it to yours

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is you are trying to get the extension name (`path.extname`) of a list of files, while it should be done in the for loop.

Your error:

```
var newExt = path.extname(data);
```

The solution:

```
for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
    var newExt = path.extname(data[i]);
    if (newExt.toString() === extentionName.toString()) {
        console.log(data[i]);
    }
}
```

As a side note, `newExt` and `extentionName` are already strings, and thus, `toString()` is unnecessary.

Comment: Oh Great, It solves my misunderstanding. Thank you so much !